# Eslint ignore all exept js fles

Tags: javascript, eslint

How can I ignore all files in  the directory `scr/` except the `.js` files? (using a `.eslintignore` file)

I tried using

```json
scr/*
!scr/*.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single star `*` only matches filenames, if you have directories you'll need to be using `**` as part of the match:

```sh
# Exclude **/scr/
scr/
# ...but not **/scr/**/*.js
!scr/**/*.js
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it might be easier to target javascript files instead of trying to ignore all other files. Something like `eslint scr/**/*.js`

Comment: Thank you too, but sadly I can only  accept one answer <3